# How to use Debug Backtrace in magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, debug

In magento 1.x we can use backtrace like

```
echo Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, true); exit;
```

How can we use this facility in Magento 2?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) as I added below.

```
$debugBackTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
foreach ($debugBackTrace as $item) {
    echo @$item['class'] . @$item['type'] . @$item['function'] . "\n";
}
```

For reference please check
 `dev\tests\api-functional\framework\Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\Webapi\Adapter\Rest\DocumentationGenerator.php`

Comment: I edited your answer. There was a piece of incorrect syntax, also I changed it to have better output (I used `@` to ignore warnings, for instance when `'class'` doesn't exist)

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev thanks for the answer it works for me

Comment: Does not work in *vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php* in the method `launch`

Answer (score 20):

In the logger classes of Magento 2, the `debug_backtrace` method is not used directly.

So the Magento 2 way of doing backtrace is to use the `Magento\Framework\Debug` class (which is the equivalent of the M1 `Varien_Debug` class) and call the `backtrace()` method:

```
/**
 * Prints or returns a backtrace
 *
 * @param bool $return      return or print
 * @param bool $html        output in HTML format
 * @param bool $withArgs    add short arguments of methods
 * @return string|bool
 */
public static function backtrace($return = false, $html = true, $withArgs = true)
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    return self::trace($trace, $return, $html, $withArgs);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Please add a usage example.

Answer (score 11):

In any PHP application you can just do:

```
$e = new \Exception();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($e->getTraceAsString()); 
exit;
```

Due to name spacing in M2, you need to use `new \Exception();` instead of just `new Exception();`

Comment: thanks for the answer i tried that but it says class Exception' not found in path of my calling class

Comment: @AshishMadankar - see edit!

Comment: Or shorter: `print_r((new \Exception())->getTraceAsString());` (since PHP 5.4, so safe to use in M2)

Comment: @ParasSood its also working

Answer (score 2):

This could also work:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$debugBackTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
foreach ($debugBackTrace as $item) {
    $logger->info(@$item['class'] . @$item['type'] . @$item['function']);
}
```

If you want to see all of the classes and methods called, in a custom log file .

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP function [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace) to debugging in Magento.

Use following code in magento to track the issue by using debug_backtrace

```
foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) {
    echo ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' .
        ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' .
        ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : '').'<br/><hr/>';
 }
exit();
```

You will see the debug backtrace that will allow you to define the issue source and you will get an idea how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\Magento\Framework\Debug::backtrace(false, true, false);
exit();
```

Or use this if you want to get the response in a logfile:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$response = \Magento\Framework\Debug::backtrace(true, false, false);
$logger->info($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the native Magento backtrace function from the `\Magento\Framework\Debug` class and call it whenever you need:

```
\Magento\Framework\Debug::backtrace(false, true, false);
```

As a result, you will get this nice HTML debug-backtrace:
[image]

If you don't like the look of the default Magento backtrace, you can use a custom function and Just copy this code into your PHP class temporarily:

```
public static function debugHtmlBacktrace($title = '') {
     $result = '';
     foreach(debug_backtrace() as $_stack) {
         $result .= '<tr>
             <td>' . (isset($_stack['file']) ? $_stack['file'] : '') . '</td>
             <td>' . (isset($_stack['line']) ? $_stack['line'] : '') . '</td>
             <td>' . (isset($_stack['function']) ? $_stack['function'] : '') . '</td>
         </tr>';
    }

    return '<br/>' . $title . '<table border="1">
         <tr><td>File</td><td>Line</td><td>Function</td></tr>' . $result . '</table>';
 }
```

and execute it by:

```
echo self::debugHtmlBacktrace();
```

**Result**:-
[image]